# calculate sum total of all the figures in a column

Tags: php, mysql

[image: table products]

I have a table that I want to calculate the sum total of all the values in column "Price" and echo the results. I have seen MySQL statement SELECT sum(column) FROM table but I am finding it difficult to use it in PHP and echo the results.

Comment: If you show your current non-working code, you will get more relevant help, as people will be able to point out your errors and get you on the right track. There's also the chance that the right answer won't help you because you have other non-related errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($db);

$sql = "select sum(column) from table";
$q = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($q);

echo 'Sum: ' . $row[0];
```

Replace variable names and table/column names as needed.

Comment: I have series of mysql databases in my server. The names of these databases are stored in a database table (users) - column(dbname) . I want to loop through table (users), get the
dbnames, connect to each and perform the above operation on each database. How do I perform such looping? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do your select.

Get the value.

Echo it.

Thats just as much as I can help right now since i have no idea what you tried so far.

For example:

```
$some_q = " SELECT SUM(some_col) AS `count_col` FROM some_table";

$results = mysql_query($some_q) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
     echo $row['count_col'];
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I have only connected to the db.

Comment: Then why post a question before you try?!?!

Comment: This query would count the number of rows rather than summing the values in the column.

Comment: "Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): 5 is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\count.php on line 57". thanks for the examples code I replaces the column and the table but I get the above error

Comment: @user75 thats bc i made an error and used `results` once and `result` the other. it is fixed now

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT sum(column) FROM tablename";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$total_savings = $row[0];
```