# How do I calculate the total of a query result in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sum, echo, calculated-columns

I was wondering if I could get some help echoing the sum of each column based on a query result. [Screenshot of table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F4hu.png)

```
<?php

if ($stationid=="") {
$query  = "select * from " . $tablename . " where  date_created >= '" . $startdate . "' and date_created <= '" . $enddate . "' and status='1' order by id desc"; ?>

$result = do_query($query);
$total = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($total>0) {
while($row = do_fetch_result($result)){
?>

<?php 
$sum_static = $row['SUM(element_10)'];
$sum_gif = $row['SUM(element_11)'];
$sum_ibv = $row['SUM(element_12)'];
$sum_html5 = $row['SUM(element_13)'];
$sum_landing = $row['SUM(element_14)'];
$sum_revs = $row['SUM(element_15)'];
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $sum_static; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $sum_ibv; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $sum_gif; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $sum_html5; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $sum_landing; ?></td>
<td colspan=1><?php echo $sum_revs; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM(...) ... GROUP BY` ? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help the community answer your question, please provide more details around what you want to sum. Even looking at your screenshot, it's unclear what you want the outcome to be.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to echo the sum of each column below the list of results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculate sum total of all the figures in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064434/calculate-sum-total-of-all-the-figures-in-a-column)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If we need to calculate sum from individual rows (if all we want to return is totals, then this is not the most efficient way to get totals), we could initialize the `$sum_foo` variables to zero...

```
$sum_static = 0;
$sum_foo    = 0;
```

And then for each row fetched, add the column value to the running total.

```
$sum_static += $row['static'];
$sum_foo  c += $row['foo'];
```

After the last row is fetched, the `$sum_foo` variables will have the total for that column for all rows.

---

In terms of performance, this is a very inefficient way to get just totals. We can have the database return the totals. We ditch the `*` in the SELECT list, and specify aggregate functions in the SELECT list:

```
 SELECT SUM(static)   AS sum_static
      , SUM(foo)      AS sum_foo
   FROM ...
```

Execute the query, and fetch the *one* row that is returned, and the row will have the precomputed totals...

```
 $row['sum_static']
 $row['sum_foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify columns name with aggregate function.

```
SELECT SUM(column1),SUM(column2)
 FROM tablename
```

Comment: I tried this, the calculation works and echoes, but the list disappears.

Comment: I am not getting the exact issue you need sum of all columns right then after fetching how it can disappear

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$overallstatic="0";
$overallgif="0";
$overallibv="0";
$overallhtml5="0";
$overalllanding="0";
$overallrev="0";
<?

<?php
$overallstatic=$overallstatic+$row['element_10'];
$overallgif=$overallgif+$row['element_11'];
$overallibv=$overallibv+$row['element_12'];
$overallhtml5=$overallhtml5+$row['element_13'];
$overalllanding=$overalllanding+$row['element_14'];
$overallrev=$overallrev+$row['element_15'];
?>

<?php
<td><?php echo $overallstatic; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $overallibv; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $overallgif; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $overallhtml5; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $overalllanding; ?></td>
<td colspan=1><?php echo $overallrev; ?></td>
?>
```

This worked.

Comment: this seems very close to to what I suggested in my answer.